# node.js set property from string property name

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I was trying to create a function able to set a certain value of an object, having the "path" of the property:

```
reflectionSet = function(obj, propString, value) {
    var current = obj;
    var splitted = propString.split('.');
    splitted.forEach(function(k) {
        current = current[k];
    })
    current = value;
}
var test = {
    a: {
        s: 'asd',
        g: 'asasdasdd'
    }
};

reflectionSet(test, 'a.g', "otherValue");
```

and it should become:

```
{
    a: {
        s: 'asd',
        g: 'otherValue'
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work at all.. Thanks

Comment: That is because JavaScript is "pass-by-value". Which means that when you collect the variable g you wont be changing the value in the Object. Just the value you collected from the Object. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value) is a more informative explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split the properties based on `.` and then using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), get to the inner most part of the Object and update it like this

```
function reflectionSet(obj, propString, value) {
    return propString.split(".").reduce(function(result, part, index, array) {
        if (index === array.length - 1) {
            result[part] = value;
            return obj;
        }
        return result[part];
    }, obj);
}

var test = {
    a: {
        s: 'asd',
        g: 'asasdasdd'
    }
};

console.log(reflectionSet(test, 'a.g', "otherValue"));
```

**Output**

```
{
    a: {
        s: 'asd',
        g: 'otherValue'
    }
}
```

Comment: currentItam is not set

Comment: @rodi Oops, there was a typo. I fixed it now. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

This corrected version of your function should do it.

```
reflectionSet = function(obj, prop, value) {
    prop = prop.split('.');
    var root = obj, i;
    for(i=0; i<prop.length; i++) {
        if(typeof root[prop[i]] == 'undefined') root[prop[i]] = {};
        if(i === prop.length - 1) root[prop[i]] = value;
        root = root[prop[i]];
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Now:

```
var test = { a: { s: 'asd', g: 'asasdasdd' } };
reflectionSet(test, 'a.g', "otherValue");
```

Will return `{ a: { s: 'asd', g: 'otherValue' } }`